# Is it possible to remove internal domain from the Excluded Address list after enabling Einstein Activity Capture?

Tags: einstein-activity-capture

Salesforce adds the default internal domain to the excluded list so that emails and events between users in our company aren’t added to Salesforce records or synced is something I found in help documents.
Let's say I have a requirement where users/Attendees are internal having their email as a part of internal domain. I want to sync up the meetings & Events into Salesforce record by adding this user in Contact roles (I tried with some Gmail users and it works) but, I am unable to do so because their email address is part of internal domain and it is by default excluded. Is there a way by which I could remove the internal domain from Excluded address list or sync their events/meetings into salesforce?

Comment: Ddi you find out if it was possible at all ? looks like SF is making the decision for us.

Answer (score 1):

Per [Considerations for Excluding Data from Einstein Activity Capture](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.aac_add_excluded_addresses_considerations.htm&type=5)

> Internal domains can’t be deleted from the excluded addresses list when the domain matches the primary email address (the email on the user record) of any
>
> - Salesforce admin
> - Salesforce user with the Customize Application or Modify All Data permissions

Steps to remove the default internal domain from excluded list are mentioned here [Remove an Excluded Address from Einstein Activity Capture](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000359054&type=1).

In a nutshell if you want to have emails from internal domain to be recorded through Einstein Activity Capture then you'd need to change email address of every user in your org who have the permissions Customize Application or Modify All Data (usually such users are System Admins). Not convenient indeed!

Answer (score 0):

You need to submit the order form supplement for Einstein feature .
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000323394&type=1

Follow all the steps in above link.

Order form supplement : https://www.salesforce.com/content/dam/web/en_us/www/documents/legal/misc/order-form-supplement-for-einstein-features.pdf?bc=OTH

Answer (score 0):

It does appear not to be possible at all anymore:

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A99NASAZ

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_sales_productivity_eac_internal_domains.htm&type=5&release=228

https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdlIvUAJ/allow-internal-domain-for-einstein-activity-capture-for-emails?sfdcIFrameOrigin=null

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.